# HL7 FHIR mark resources as anonymized

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am trying to map an existing domain into HL7 FHIR. 
So far it was pretty easy to find FHIR resources that more or less represent the same data and can be used for that purpose. But now  I am running into a problem of which I am not sure how to solve it.

The existing domain allows that data can be anonymized depending on the users access level. e.g. a patient's name or address might be removed and marked as anonymized. Other data will be pseudonymised, for example a the birthdate in 1980 will be replaced with 01.01.1980. An Age of 37 will be replaced with a category of 30-40.

So I am unsure how to integrate that into the FHIR domain. I was thinking I could create an *extension* holding a boolean, indicating if a value was anonymized or not and always replace or remove the original value. This might work, but I will run into big problems when the anonymized value is of a different type than the original value (e.g. Age is replaced by a range of values)

Is that even a valid approach? I thought this might be common problem, but I could not find any examples where people described methods of how to mark data as altered. Unfortunately the documentation at http://build.fhir.org/extensibility-registry.html does not contain anything that would help my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use security labels for this purpose (Resource.meta.security).  Take a look at REDACTED and SUBSETTED in the security label value set: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-security-labels.html

If you need to convey a data type other than the one allowed by the resource (e.g. wanting to convey a range rather than a birthdate), you'd need to use an extension.  (Note that dates are valid even if you only include the year.)